# How to install thin strips of laminate flooring around heating register

Tags: laminate-floor

I can't come up with a way to put LVP around this heating register in a way that meets the manufacturer's recommendations for width.  And there will be no molding over the rightmost edge, only some silicone caulk against the tub.

Any suggestions here?  Perhaps I should glue it to the plywood subfloor?  [image]

Comment: How is the rest of the floor installed?  Is it glued down, or is it floating?

Comment: It's floating, not glued.

Comment: I would glue it to the subfloor with a couple of dabs of an appropriate adhesive. Given it's location, it's probably not going to see any foot traffic that would cause it to shift.  You're just taking about the 3" section, right?  There should be no need to glue the piece that runs along the "top" edge of the register - the 4" wide section.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes just the 3" section.